# Displaying data table from database on jsp in the form of table using servlet in java mvc?

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am developing website using `servlet` and `jsp`.I want to retrieve data from a table and display it on a `table` in the jsp, but jsp should not contain any processing code. All processing code should be in servlet. Can anyone please help me out.

Comment: This is far too vague. It all sounds fairly standard stuff. Have you taken a tutorial to understand all the concepts? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform queries in your servlet and put your result in a place accessible also to the jsp (like session or request attributes).
Then in your jsp you can loop the result (try searching on google how to use jstl taglib) and print them as you wish.
Hope this helps.

Found this on github that may help you: https://github.com/danielniko/SimpleJspServletDB

Answer (score 0):

Do the database query in some servlets and obtained results you should set in the request using below statements,

```
ArrayList<Table_8> data = (ArrayList) dao.select();
request.setAttribute("databaseResults", databaseResults);
request.getRequestDispatcher("xyzJsp.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Now in your JSP, use something like below,

```html
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.databaseResults}" var="element" varStatus="loop">
  <tr>
    <td>${loop.index+1}</td>
    <td>${element.title}</td>
    <td>${element.platform}</td>
    <td>${element.score}</td>
    <td>${element.genre}</td>
    <td>${element.editorsChoice}</td>
  </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

where `element` is a type of `valueobject/POJO` class, which consists of all those attributes.

For more information please check [Web application using Servlets,JSP,Bootstrap and database](https://github.com/devrishal/SynchronyFinancialChallenge/)